# Custom Wifi hotspot with Facebook or Twitter login

Tags: facebook, twitter, oauth, wifi

I would like to install a custom Wi-fi hotspot which needs login to enable Internet access with this requirements and I would like to know if someone has installed.

Requirements:

- **Login server:** I have my own OAuth server built with Java/Spring to
  enable user login with Twitter and Facebook via REST API.
- **Wi-fi access point:** allows user Internet access when login success.
- When the user selects the Wi-Fi network, the landing page must appear with the login button.

I' ve got the login module, but I don' t know how to install some kind of Wi-fi hotspot with a custom landing page that could link with this login server. I've searched for some kind of tool or software, but I found nothing. Any ideas or suggestions, please?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is this a software or a hardware thing you are looking for?

Comment: It combines both: hardware, because you need a router to connect with; software, because I want to develop a way to authenticate users and then allow them Internet access if the login succes. It' s important for me to manage the login process myself, because I want to access to some user account info - no external authentication service will fit for me. I´ve got the software part, because I have developped some time ago an application that authenticates users with OAuth protocol, but I need some kind of help, suggestions... with the second part of the project.

Comment: The second part of the project involves that way to interact with the router to grant Internet access to those users that I accept after OAuth login process.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled over a [google code project](http://www.google-melange.com/gsoc/project/details/google/gsoc2012/ntmq90/5668600916475904) which achieves what you want for routers running openwrt.

The basic setup is this: You run a router with openwrt (a list of supported Hardware can be found [on their wiki](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start)). Then you install [wifidog](http://dev.wifidog.org) to provide your portal page and run the project (which now seeems to have moved [here and has been renamed to KikiAuth](https://github.com/hongquan/KikiAuth)) as the auth provider for wifidog.

Since KikiAuth is opensource it should be easy to adopt the method it uses to provide the auth information for wifidog into your existing software and use it as the provider instead if you want to manage the login process yourself.

More details about the setup can be found on the [page of the google code project](http://www.google-melange.com/gsoc/project/details/google/gsoc2012/ntmq90/5668600916475904).